# Need help with a macros for Visual Studio to cancel outlining at file open

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros, code-regions

As you can guess from the title, the outlining with regions finally made me sick.

I remember reading in comments somewhere that it is possible to have a macros to perform this task. Since I haven't ever written a single macros fro VS, I ask for community assistance.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For VB**,

Tools –> Options –> Text Editor –> Basic –> VB Specific –> Enter outlining mode when files open.

**For C#,**

Tools –> Options –> Text Editor –> C# -> Advanced -> Enter outlining mode when files open.

**For C/C++,**

Tools –> Options –> Text Editor –> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Enter outlining mode when files open.